# Filter для вложенных массивов

Tags: javascript

Есть структура объекта такая, 
Как я могу сделать поиск простой через filter или подобные конструкции чтобы к  он вернул тот же массив, только с language = rus, удалив к примеру только массив c language = eng, 
делаю это вложенным циклом и методом splice, что то как то не эффективно это для js.

```
[
 {
    id: 40,
    code: 5345,
    "dictor": {
              "id": 545,
               "values": [
                         {
                           "id": 6345,
                           "language": "rus"
                         },
                         {
                           "id": 634335,
                           "language": "eng"
                         }
                         ]
                }            
         }
},     {
      id: 40,
    code: 5345,
    "dictor": {
              "id": 545,
               "values": [
                         {
                           "id": 6345,
                           "language": "rus"
                         },
                         {
                           "id": 634335,
                           "language": "eng"
                         }
                         ]
                }            
      }
```

}

Comment: просто в json строке регуляркой отпилите все конструкции вида `,
                         {
                           "id": 634335,
                           "language": "eng"
                         }`, хотя я не понимаю чем помешал лишний элемент в строке

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не красиво

Comment: почему ты думаешь что твой метод был неэффективным?

Comment: Кажется есть более элегантный способ это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
  id: 40,
  code: 5345,
  dictor: {
    id: 545,
    values: [
      { id: 6345, language: 'rus' },
      { id: 634335, language: 'eng' }
    ]
  }            
}, {
  id: 40,
  code: 5345,
  dictor: {
    id: 545,
    values: [
      { id: 6345, language: 'rus' }, 
      { id: 634335, language: 'eng' }
    ]
  }            
}];


function filterByLanguage(data, language) {
  return data.filter(function(record) {
    record.dictor.values = record.dictor.values.filter(function(item) {
      return item.language === language;
    });
    return record.dictor.values.length; 
  });  
}

var result = filterByLanguage(data, 'rus');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо.